# Hybris backoffice menu changed as hMC menu

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I accidentally check "clear the hMC configuration from the database" when I should have just chose
update running system and localize types. And my backoffice menu changed as same as hMC menu.

eventhough I initialized it was same.

is there any way to let the system read the setting from the backoffice-config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset this config through the backoffice.

After you are logged into the backoffice (with a user that belongs to the admingroup), press `f4` to access the application orchestrator mode. In this screen you can reset your backoffice configuration.

There are 3 options that can be used to reset configuration. This depends on what exactly you want to reset. If all config can be reset, just go for `Reset Everything`

[image]

Comment: I tried reset everything and nothing changed. it maintained the non-customized menus, but problem solved by copying cockpit-config.xml from production server..but I have one other problem. when i click the customized menu from production server's backoffice menus it shows "No type selected" message. but my dev, local work fine..

Comment: well the reset everything takes the *-config.xml files from your server and uses those to do the reset. If the file does not contain the changes, it will not take the correct items